# Is it alright for a React child component to alter data stored in its parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The React docs recommend the following for storing data in a component:

- `props` are meant to pass on and store immutable data
- `state` is meant to store dynamic data **which is rendered**
- data that is not rendered and is dynamic can be stored in the instance's attributes defined in any method as `this.attribute`

So my question is, that is it alright to have a child component changes its parent's data?

This is recommended by the docs for changing state that lives in an ancestor component. **However, the data I'm working with is not rendered and so is saved as an attribute.** Is it recommended for me to modify it from the child component using a callback function?

***Just for clarification, I'm not talking about changing `props` or the `state`. I want to change a class attribute living in the parent.***

React docs suggest that mutable data that is not rendered be stored in a simple attribute.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: props cannot be changed and they are not even meant to. The callback approach from parent to child which changes the state of parent is just the right thing to do.

Comment: Pass a props function to your children. Change state in parent when this function is called.
You should (and can't) never change props value.

Answer (score 4):

An option is to use callback.
Here you expose a callback from parent, which changes parent data (state), the child component uses a prop which get its data from parent's state. That is it!

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';


class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    console.log(`Child Component Data is ${data}`);
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.props.onChange('Success!')} }>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 30}}>{data}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: 'default data in parent'
    }
  }

  onChange = (data) => {
    console.log(`Data changes to ${data} !`);
    this.setState({ data });
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return <Child data={data} onChange={this.onChange}></Child>;
  }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('ChildEditParentData', () => Parent);
```

Update:

> Facebook has a nice tutorial on similar issue, and Facebook names this as "[Lifting State Up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html)"

Comment: This is also the way that the React docs recommend you do things - see [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) and [Lifting State Up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: The suggested flow in react stays the same, no matter if you're changing state in a parent or a class attribute.

Comment: @David Thanks for your answer. As my questions suggests, I'm aware that this is the recommended way to change the state of a parent inside a child component. However, I'm talking about a data attribute living in the parent. Not about the state nor props (like some comments above suggest). So would you recommend changing a plain old class attribute living the parent using the above callback method? Appreciate your help!